# matplotlib axis limit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to set a 'minimum' axis limit - in other words, I want to `set_ylim([0, 30])`, but adding point at y = 40 would have the axis grow to accommodate it. Is there any combination of limits and autoscaling that could achieve this for me?

Comment: Can you post a simple self contained sample that exhibits the incorrect behavior?

Comment: this is what matplotlib does for me by default... (Python 2.6.5, matplotlib 0.99.1.1, Ubuntu Linux)

Answer (score 2):

```
set_ylim(ymin=0)
```

[Documentation.](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim)

Interesting, the [API recently changed to](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/api_changes.html?highlight=ymin#changes-beyond-0-99-x) `bottom` and `top`:

```
set_ylim(bottom=0)
```

although `ymin` and `ymax` are still legal.